# Using regular expression can we take the even placed and odd placed value?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var testSt = "Hello"
testSt.split('').filter((a,b)=>{if(b==0||b%2==0){return a}}).join('') // to get even placed value Hlo
```

It is possible to do by looping through the values, and check if the index is divided by 2 or not. Is it possible to directly write a regular expression and exec on string to get the even placed and odd placed values?

```
Example - testSt.exec(/^\d*[024]$/) //something like this
```

Comment: Nitpick: `0%2==0` so `b==0||` is redundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
console.log('abcdefghij'.replace(/(.)./g, '$1'));
```

The `.` in a RegExp will match anything, so `/../` is a way to match a pair of characters. Using the `g` modifier will cause all pairs of characters in the string to be matched. Such a match is performed without overlap between the matches, so `ab`, `cd`, `ef`, `gh` and `ij`.

By putting `()` around the first `.` it will form a capture group on the first character of each pair. The `$1` is a special syntax used to refer to the first capture group, so each pair will be replaced by the first character of that pair.

So, for example, the first matching pair in the string is `ab` and the `a` will be captured. `ab` will therefore be replaced by `a`. It will then replace `cd` with `c`, `ef` with `e` and so on.

It is worth noting that for a string with an odd length the final character will not be matched but that isn't a problem because we don't want to replace it. This would be a problem if we wanted to swap the roles of odd digits and even digits, so we couldn't just move the parentheses. To get that to work we'd have to make the second character optional at the end of the string. We can do that using a `$` character, which matches the end of the string:

```js
// This leaves a trailing letter i at the end, which is wrong
console.log('abcdefghi'.replace(/.(.)/g, '$1'));

// Fixed
console.log('abcdefghi'.replace(/.(.|$)/g, '$1'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Skirtle, can you give little explaination for the answer

Comment: @VinodkumarG Done.